# positioning elements randomly in a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

i'm writing a fastfood app , basically allowing users to custom their pitza by adding stuff to it .

so , i show a simple pitza to them and on the sidebar they have all this stuff ... like pepperoni , beef , mushroom and ...

```
<div id = "pitz" style="background-image: url("pitza.png");" > </div>

<div class="custom" id="pepperoni">peppeoni</div>
<div class="custom" id="beef">beef </div>
<div class="custom" id="mushroom">mushroom </div>
```

so when user clicks on the custom divs like `mushroom` i want to add little mushrooms to my pitza ... something like

```
$('.custom').click(function(e) {

    var backgroung = $(this).attr('id')+'.png';

    for( i = 0 ; i < 40 ; i++ )
    {
        var top , left = i ;

        var add = '<div style="top:'+top+'px ; left:'+left+'px ; width:100;height:100px;background-image:url("'+background+'");" ></div>';
        $('#pitza').append(add);
    }

});
```

so here is the problem , in order to add little items (mushrooms)  to my parent item (pitza)  i need to position them ... in this case in a circle (pitza) so i need to generate random position for each item so they don't overlap also these positions should be in a imaginary circle and it should cover all parts of circle , i dont want left side empty and right side full of mushrooms .

obviously this doesn't work and i have no idea how to do it :

```
for( i = 0 ; i < 40 ; i++ )
{
    var top , left = i ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're looking at two circles, one with the radius of your pizza, and one with the radius of your topping. So you'd do something like this.

```
var pizzaRadius = 200,
    toppingRadii = {
        mushroom: 40,
        pepperoni: 50,
        onions: 25
    };

function getToppingPosition(toppingRadius){
   var posX, posY;
   do {
       posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((pizzaRadius * 2) - 1));
       posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((pizzaRadius * 2) - 1));
   } while(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pizzaRadius - posX, 2) + Math.pow(pizzaRadius - posY, 2)) > pizzaRadius - toppingRadius)

   return { x: posX, y: posY }
}
```

Basically what that function does is gets a random number within the bounds of the pizza and makes sure that the position + the size of the topping is on the pizza (so there's no toppings hanging over the edge. After that you'd just plug that function into your loop

```
$('.custom').click(function(e) {

    var backgroung = $(this).attr('id')+'.png',
        topping = 'mushroom';

    for( i = 0 ; i < 40 ; i++ )
    {
        var pos = getToppingPosition(toppingRadii[topping])

        var add = '<div style="top:'+pos.x+'px ; left:'+pos.y+'px ; width:100;height:100px;background-image:url("'+background+'");" ></div>';
        $('#pitza').append(add);
    }

});
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/19h242yc/